# How to write an ArrayList when instantiating?

Tags: java, arraylist, instances

Probably I'm being blind or something, but I can't seem to figure out how to do the following:

I have a Class called Shopping with a constructor like this:

```
Shopping shopping = new Shopping(String name, ArrayList <Shop> shops)
```

The class Shop is superclass for 4 types of sub-shops, and its constructor is something like this:

```
Shop shop = new Shop(String name, double area, double income)
```

My question is: when creating a Shopping instance I don't know what to write on the Array list part of the constructor, like I can create a

```
Shopping s1 = new Shopping("ABCDE", ?????? <- but don't know what to write here!!!)
```

Any help?

Comment: Depends how you're creating your shop list. You could create it first then pass it to the constructor, or if you're creating it later make a constructor that only receives `string name` and sets `shops` to null inside the constructor (or creates an empty list), then fill the list later

Comment: @Zabuza Please don't answer questions in the comments. Comments are for gathering more information to improve or clarify the question.

Comment: @DavidConrad Sometimes I don't have the time to write an answer so detailed that I would want to paste it as answer. Because an answer should fully solve the issue, clarifying all confusion. In that case it's good to just paste the short high level description as comment. But in this case I realized that I want to extend and write an answer, so I just removed the comment after writing the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation

You create a new instance of the object using

```
ArrayList<Shop> shops = new ArrayList<>();
```

and then you add your stuff

```
shops.add(firstShop);
shops.add(secondShop);
```

and after that you just pass the variable to the method

```
Shopping s1 = new Shopping("ABCDE", shops);
```

Or if you want to pass an empty list you can simply do it in one line

```
Shopping s1 = new Shopping("ABCDE", new ArrayList<>());
```

---

### Other lists

Is there a particular reason you need to limit the method to `ArrayList`s? Wouldn't `List` be enough too? If you adjust that you can pass other lists too and with Java 9 there is a simple way to create lists quickly:

```
List<Shop> shops = List.of(firstShop, secondShop);
Shopping s1 = new Shopping("ABCDE", shops);
```

Or even more compact:

```
Shopping s1 = new Shopping("ABCDE", List.of(firstShop, secondShop));
```

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you need to pass it an instance of the type you've declared.  If that type is `ArrayList<Shop>` then you need to pass it one of those.  You can create one of those with `new ArrayList()', for example, or you might have some code that constructs such a list, or even that already has one because it was doing something else with a list of shops.

However, you've backed yourself into a corner by saying it has to be an `ArrayList`. You should only declare it to take a List, and only if the order of the shops is important.  If the order isn't important, then just declare a `Collection<Shop>`.  Always declare your arguments to be as non-specific as you can.  If it's a Collection, then someone who happens to have a `Set<Shop>` in his hand can pass it to you, and it will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Two possibilities. If you've previously created some shops:

```
Shop subShop = new Shop("Subway", 2000, 4000);
Shop bookShop = new Shop("B&N", 8000, 9000);
```

And a list:

```
ArrayList<Shop> shops = new ArrayList<>();
shops.add(subShop);
shops.add(bookShop);
```

Then you can create it like this:

```
Shopping shopping = new Shopping("Plaza", shops);
```

However, I would change `Shopping` to take a `List` (or even a `Collection`, as Zag points out), rather than an `ArrayList` in which case you can do this:

```
Shopping shopping = new Shopping("Plaza", List.of(subShop, bookShop));
```

You can even write it all in one line, if you put the calls to the `Shop` constructors inside the call to `List::of`.

Answer (score 1):

```
Shopping shopping = new Shopping(name, new ArrayList<>());
```

or if you want a list that already has some items in it:

```
List<Shop> shops = new ArrayList<>();
shops.add(new Shop(...));
shops.add(new Shop(...));
Shopping shopping = new Shopping(name, shops);
```

You can also do that in one line, if you want:

```
Shopping shopping = new Shopping(name, Arrays.asList(new Shop(...), new Shop(...)));
```

Comment: `new List<>()` isn't valid Java. `List` is an interface and can't be instantiated.

Comment: @DavidConrad whoops, fixed it. My bad.

Comment: I should've let you make the post for me. Multitasking isn't doing too well for me right now ;~; Thanks again @DavidConrad

Comment: By the way, the last works only if the method takes general `List`s too. Because the list returned by `Arrays.asList` is not `ArrayList` (it has the same name though, but it actually is a different class implemented in the `Arrays` class).

Comment: @Zabuza `new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("a", "b"))` it can still be used like so, assuming that he really does use ArrayList instead of List as parameter